# How do i randomly select something from a table?

Tags: vb.net

Dim lolthisisatable = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"}
I'm trying to select a string randomly from this table "lolthisisatable"
like **(insert code that selects a string randomly from that table)**
string "2" was choosen randomly

how do i do that in Visual Basic 2010

Comment: No im just trying to make a program that generates names randomly. im also trying to learn VB

Comment: That's not a table by any means...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code `lolthisisatable(New Random().Next(0, lolthisisatable.Length-1))`

Comment: wow thanks so much man now i can make a random name generator :D